# rust Option ok_or without unwrap()? looking for value_or function

Tags: rust, rust-result

I am making a function that returns a Result<MyValue, &str> because there are so many Ok Results, and Some Option that need unwrapping inside my function. I wanted to use **?**, be able to return Result errors, and not live inside a 20 layer unwrapped if let Some(a) = b and if let Ok(a) = b function. as such I have been using

```
fn from_ui(ui:&HtmlElement) -> Result<MyValue, &str> 
{
  let a = ui.get_attribute("data-my").ok_or("Value. Error 0");
  let a = a.unwrap(); 
  ... 
}
```

my issue is that I need to do 'let a = a.unwrap()' because ok_or returns the Ok Result, and not the value inside of the Ok result. Is there a function I can use that is just like **.value_or("Value. Error Code 0")**

I find the additional unwrap tedious. It also basically doubles the size of the function without adding any value. I've done .ok_or("Value. Error 0").unwrap() to reduce the number of lines of code and that does work.

I have also looked at all the unwrap_or... variations but those appear to return a default value to the left-hand-side variable instead of returning from the function with an Error string. In swift this is known as a **guard** I would not like to use any crates if possible.

Comment: Wouldn't you just use [`?` to return early](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html#propagating-errors)?

Comment: Yeah, wouldn't this just be `.ok_or("Value. Error 0")?;`? (with the `?` after `.ok_or()`).

Comment: If I use ? to return early, is it possible to customize the Err message string?

Comment: What do you mean by "customize the Err message string"? You are already providing `"Value. Error 0"` as the error message.

Comment: I mean that when you do something like parse::<uint>()? the error message is a system error message - whereas I would like to customize my error message I'm also not sure if ui.get_attribute("data-my").ok_or("Value. Error 0").unwrap() would short-circuit at the ok_or or not and prevent unwrap() crashing

Comment: The `ok_or` will not prevent the `unwrap()` crashing. It converts an `Option` to a `Result` with the specified error value if the option was empty. So if it is empty, the unwrap will panic with the error you passed to `ok_or`.